# UML Statechart Diagrams + Navigation Bar + Multiple exit actions

Tags: database, uml, statechart

Hope all is well! I am making a UML statechart diagram for a website. If you have a navigation bar, would/can you have multiple exit actions representing each link?

Comment: What is a "navigation bar"?

Comment: @ThomasKilian like a menu bar that links to different pages. For example, on stackoverflow its Questions, Jobs, Documentation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is only one exit behavior that can be defined (p. 307):

> **14.2.3.4.3 State entry, exit, and doActivity Behaviors**
>   A State may have an associated entry Behavior. This Behavior, if defined, is executed whenever the State is entered through an external Transition. In addition, a State may also have an associated exit Behavior, which, if defined, is executed whenever the State is exited.

Also in later passages they only talk of `exit` with singular. E.g.

> **14.2.3.4.6 Exiting a State**
>   When exiting a State, regardless of whether it is simple or composite, the final step involved in the exit, after all other Behaviors associated with the exit are completed, is the execution of the exit Behavior of that State. If the State has a doActivity Behavior that is still executing when the State is exited, that Behavior is aborted before the exit Behavior commences execution.

So you will need to test the state transition inside the `exit` behavior to take according actions.

N.B. I'm using Enterprise Architect which allows definition of multiple `exit` behaviors. There is no way to define any guard which affirms my assumption about only a single `exit` to be allowed. So the implementation is likely broken here.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other responses, there is a single exit action.

However, you can have multiple transitions existing the state (one for each navigation bar item), each with its own trigger(s), guard(s), and behaviour.

Depending on your workflow, these could either be self-transition (coming back to the same state) or go to another system state. These could also be internal (e.g., the state is not exited when the transition is taken.